# PHP not sending email for contact form

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

After filling in the required fields the contact form is supposed to process the information inputted by the user and sent off in an email format to the receiver which in this instance is the website owner. However after the page auto refreshes nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated. I have included the code below which also has the PHP embedded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head**strong text**>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contact - Dream Occasions</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Dream Occasions</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="contact.html" style="background-color:#3366ff">Contact</a></li>
                  <div class="header-icons">
                  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/irelanddreamoccasions/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"style="font-size: 0.90em;"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"style="font-size: 0.90em; padding-left:20px;"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/sconboy2002/?eq=suzanne%20conboy&etslf=10321"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"style="font-size: 0.90em; padding-left:20px;"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /container -->
    </div>
    <div class="contact">  
                <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
                    <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
                    <h4>Contact us for a free consultation.</h4>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="Name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="Email" name="Email" tabindex="2" required>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="Tel" name="Tel" tabindex="3">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...."  name="Message" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
                $to = "dreamoccasions@eircom.net"; // this is your Email address
                $from = $_POST['Email']; // this is the sender's Email address
                $name = $_POST['Name'];
                $tel = $_POST['Tel'];
                $submit = $_POST['submit'];
                $subject = "Form submission";
                $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
                $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['Message'];
                $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['Message'];

                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
                echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

                }
            ?>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
                <div class="footer-left">
                    <p class="footer-links">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                        <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-center">
                    <span>Contact us</span>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                        <p>Edgeworthstown, Co.Longford</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        <p>Telephone Us At - 0868558521</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        <p>dreamoccasions@eircom.net</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-right">
                    <p class="footer-company-about">
                        <span>Connect with us</span>
                        <p>On our numerous social medias to keep up to date.</p>
                    </p>
                    <div class="footer-icons">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/irelanddreamoccasions/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/sconboy2002/?eq=suzanne%20conboy&etslf=10321"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <p class="footer-company-name"><span>Dream Occasions &copy; 2017. All Rights Reserved.</span>
                <span>Site Developed By Joel Conboy</span>
                <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
                </p>
            </footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is probably not a duplicate, but a typo in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have `<button name="submit"` but you are checking `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){`. You have a case mismatch. Call your button `Submit` instead and it should work.